# Four hours to go till public!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, beta-progress

I think we've done a really nice job of seeding the site with questions and answers that will make experts want to participate.

Looking at [the stats on area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters), 69 percent of those who committed as well as 49 percent of those that followed signed up for the private beta. I think that gave us enough unique personalities with knowledge to bring to the table to start what should be a rather nice, knowledgeable and helpful community.

Jeff and Robert, I'm wondering .. how did we do in private beta and most importantly where should we focus on improving during the public beta?

Personally, I think we need to work a little more on tags, as well as our own promotional tools (even though Stack Exchange will be giving us some great stuff to use).

Thoughts?

**Edit**

This was not a feature request :)

Comment: I just love how it became "status-completed" when it launched.

Comment: @HoLyVieR - Edited. People are sometimes busy.

Answer (score 3):

So far it's a bit of a programmer's site I think; I hope there will be more non-programmer webmasters coming here.

Comment: I agree. Kevin Bacon needs more bacon. But, _some_ programming is a part of most pro webmaster's job. A pro webmaster is (broadly) considered a jack of all trades, hence our overlap with the existing trilogy sites.

Comment: We need some Geocities webmasters ! :p

Comment: We (Stack Overflow Inc) brought the programmer element here. That's what we have access to. Its up to *you* guys to bring in the rest of your industry.

Comment: I've actually really enjoyed this so far, mostly because I'm NOT a day-to-day programmer.  At SO, it always feels like there's someone more qualified answering the question, so it's great to be able to feel useful ;)

Answer (score 3):

There's been good questions and answers so far. It's nice having a site focused on website management and optimization, which is a different focus from just coding. I expect I'll be spending a lot of time here.

Answer (score 2):

Now public! Congrats.

Make use of that "Share this site!" flair to bring in other fellow webmasters. I know I have..

http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/18623087028

Comment: Great, but how did we do in the private beta? Its now marked as status-completed, but where can we improve?

Comment: Or... we think we rocked it, are we missing out on some critical component that SE feels is important? :)